# Setting up a Postgres DB for Django with Fly.io

Tags: python, django, postgresql, fly

I'm a novice trying to spin up my first webapp with a combination of Fly.io, Django, and a postgres DB but I'm having some trouble and can't find an answer in walkthroughs or Q&A.

I've set up a simple "Hello world" Django app (models.py is empty so far) and I'm trying to get all the components up and running before I build it out any further.

- I've successfully deployed my app on Fly.io with no errors
- I've created a postgres cluster on Fly.io using the instructions here: https://fly.io/docs/postgres/
- I've attached the cluster to my app, which generates a DB and sets an environment variable with the appropriate details (username, password, port, host, dbname)
- I've updated my settings.py file:

  ```
  DATABASES = {}
  DATABASES["default"] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600, ssl_require=True)
  ```
- I've added to my fly.toml:

  ```
  [[services]]
    internal_port = 5432 # Postgres instance
    protocol = "tcp"

  # Open port 10000 for plaintext connections.
  [[services.ports]]
    handlers = []
    port = 10000
  ```
- I've confirmed I can get into the psql shell with `flyctl postgres connect -a MYAPP-pg`

But unfortunately when I run `python manage.py migrate` to check that everything is working, I get the following error:

```
File "<my_path>\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 282, in ensure_connection
 self.connect()
File "<my_path>\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "<my_path>\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 263, in connect
 self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
File "<my_path>\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "<my_path>\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 215, in get_new_connection
 connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
File "<my_path>\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
 conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "top2.nearest.of.MYAPP-pg.internal" to address: Unknown host
```

Any ideas what might be happening? Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like your app is deployed outside of the network that your postgres instance is hosted on. Your hostname `top2.nearest.of.MYAPP-pg.internal` looks like an internal hostname, meaning your app should also be deployed within the same network. If you need to expose your postgres instance to outside applications, I think their docs mentioned using WireGuard to port forward the instance to your local machine: https://fly.io/docs/postgres/#connecting-to-fly-postgres-from-outside-fly

Comment: Are you executing `python manage.py migrate` locally?